# Trying to use WebDriverWait until presence_of_element_located instead of sleep.time in Selenim Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

I have this piece of code which works as it is:

```
time.sleep(0.7)

self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("anyXpath").click()
```

I make the program to wait for a time so the button on the pop-up window is really there to be clicked, and this solution works.
Now, I want to do the same but with `WEbDriverWait` and I wrote this:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "anyXpath"))

self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("anyXpath").click()
```

But the button is never clicked. What am I doing wrong? I am open to use another expected condition different from presence_of_element_located but I guess it should work with the latter also.
Thanks.

Comment: Use element to be clickable and then use .click() after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By importing `WebDriverWait`, `expected_conditions`, and `By`, you can wait until the WebDriver deems an element clickable before it clicks the element.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

WebDriverWait(10, self.driver).until(
    expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, "//xpath//to//element")
    )
).click()
```

Make sure that you pass a tuple to `element_to_be_clickable()`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work now, I exchanged "10" and "driver" positions though and used "self.driver" instead of "driver"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method. It wait for element to be click able

```
WebDriverWait(10, driver).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "anyXpath"))
```

import

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. You wrote "(10, driver)" and I tried with "10" and "driver"/"self.driver" in different positions inside the brackets. I also used expected_conditions instead of EC which I guess it's the same.

Comment: Is the part element_to_be_clickable work ? It wait for html element to be clickable

Comment: If [element_to_be_clickable] not work ? I think the problem is the pop-up window. You may need to switch to that window before you click the button.

Comment: The issue is with the values passed to `element_to_be_clickable`. That function takes a tuple. Also `By` was not imported.

Comment: Make sure you import everything needed. [element_to_be_clickable] only require a locator, so i think you should re-check whether you enter the locator right.

Comment: Thanks Trinh Phat, I added the click() part at the end and eliminated my "self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("anyXpath").click()" as Jacob Lee proposed. For some reason it works like this.

Comment: Everything was imported and I had already tried element_to_be_clickable but it's obvious that I made some mistake in the syntax.